# Javascript: Uncaught Error: Too many listeners for downloads.onDeterminingFilename

Tags: javascript

Here's the code:

```
assets.forEach(function(v) {

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.id     = "canvas";
    canvas.width  = 200;
    canvas.height = 150;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'file:///path/to/file/' + v.name;
    img.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height-256, 0, 0, 200, 150);
    };
    document.getElementById('download').addEventListener('click',
        function() {
            chrome.downloads.download({
                url: canvas.toDataURL()
            });

            chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener(
                function(downloadItem, cb) {
                    console.log(downloadItem);
                    cb({
                        filename: 'path/to/file/thumb-' + v.name.split('_')[0] + '.png',
                        conflictAction: 'overwrite'
                    });
                    return true;
                }
            );
        },
    false
    );
});
```

This works if there's only 1 file in the folder. If more, then it will work for a single file only. How can figure it out so that it will work for many files?

Please note, that it saves the new thumbnail to the same folder where the initial image is.

Comment: Why are you adding another click listener to `download` for each asset? Why are you adding a new `onDeterminingFilename` listener on every click?

Comment: Yes, I tried to move it away, so that it won't get repeated. But then a blank picture is saved, it is not taking it in the context. This way it works.

Comment: Then save your canvases/images/assets/whatever in an array and have one listener that processes each of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have more than one `onDeterminingFilename` listener:

> #### onDeterminingFilename
>
> During the filename determination process, extensions will be given the opportunity to override the target DownloadItem.filename. Each extension may not register more than one listener for this event.

[Source](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#event-onDeterminingFilename)

Comment: I ended up removing `chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener` and doing another way.